# Xcode 9 automatically manage signing and OneSignal push certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I'm developing my first app for ios. I have configured xcode 9 to automatically manage signing.

I should integrate my app with onesignal push notification, that require a push certificate from Apple.

If i have understood the complex way used from Apple to sign application, push notification is automatically signed from xcode. How can i download a copy of the automatically created certificate to import that into onesignal?

I know this is not a programming question, but is all day that i make test without any results, you are my hope guys.

Comment: Exactly which part isnt clear for you? [Signing iOS Apps for Onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate) Have you followed those steps?

Comment: As far as I know, all XCode  auto generated profiles are also available in de developer portal as well, so If you need to download one of those, just go to you portal, they will apear as `XC wildcard`